# Find all positive integer solutions for the following equation $5^a + 4^b = 3^c$:

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Find all positive integer solutions for the following equation:
> $$5^a + 4^b = 3^c$$

My first guess would be to study the equation in mod, but I tried modulo 3, 4, 5, and 9 and I can't find anything.

Comment: Is this somehow related to the use of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $$1^a + 0 \equiv _4 (-1)^c \implies c \equiv_2 0$$
so $c=2d$, $d\in \mathbb{N}$.

So $$ 5^a = (3^d-2^b)(3^d+2^b)$$

so $3^d-2^b = 5^x$ and $3^d+2^b = 5^y$. Now add/substract both equations...

---

> ...we see that $x=0$. Now if $b>1$ then we have $$(-1)^d -0 \equiv _41 $$ so $d$ is even. So we have $$(3^m-1)(3^m+1)= 2^b$$ Now $(3^m-1)$ and $(3^m+1)$ are two consecutive even numbers so exactly one is divisible by $4$ so the other number is exactly $2$.

Comment: I get $2\cdot 3^d=5^y+5^x$ and $2^{b+1}=5^y-5^x$. From this we get $x=0$, but I don't see how to go from there.

Comment: Like I said: from this we get $x=0$. So $3^d-2^b=1$, and now we need [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), don't we?

Comment: @TonyK  You don't need that theorem

Comment: @Aqua how can i find the integer solutions after this?

Comment: Everything is writen

Comment: @Aqua sorry but I still don't get what the solutions are. Can you write them as (a,b,c)=...

Comment: Well I think the equation $3^{2m}-1=2^b$ could use a line of justification. Now the equation $3^d-2^b=5^x$ combined w $x=0,d$ even gives $3^{2m}-2^b=1$ where $d=2m$, which gives $3^{2m}-1=2^b$...

Comment: OP, note that $3^m-1$ and $3^m+1$ must each be powers of 2. But $3^m-1$ and $3^m+1$ differ by only 2. This implies that $3^m-1$ has to be 2. Do you see why this is?

Comment: Let $r$ and $s$ be integers satsfying $|r| \le |s|$. Note that $|2^s-2^r| = |2^r(2^{s-r}-1)|$. If either $r$ or $s$ is negative and they are not the same then this is not an integer. What if $r \ge 2$ or $s\ge 3$?

Answer (score 1):

Another route: Follow the reasoning in Aqua's answer up to $5^a=(3^d-2^b)(3^d+2^b)$.

Then ask if $3^d-2^b$ and $3^d+2^b$ share any factors. If $m\mid (3^d-2^b) \land m \mid (3^d+2^b)$, then $m \mid (3^d-2^b)+(3^d+2^b)=2\cdot3^d$, which means $m\in\{1,2,3^x\}$. But $2\not \mid (3^d-2^b)$ and $3\not \mid (3^d-2^b)$, so $m=1$. In other words, $\gcd((3^d-2^b),(3^d+2^b))=1$

But the product of the two terms is a power of $5$, so one term must be exactly $1$ and the other term is the power of $5$. Plainly the smaller term will be $1$, so we solve $(3^d-2^b)=1$, which has only two solutions: $b=d=1$, and by Mihailescu's theorem $d=2,b=3$

Substituting into the other term, we find $3^1+2^1=5^1$ and $3^2+2^3=17 \ne 5^d$. So there is only one solution to the original equation: $5^1+4^1=3^2$